# django-tables 2 M2M field not shown

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to show a M2M field in a django-table2 as seen in [Django-tables2: How to use accessor to bring in foreign columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777125/django-tables2-how-to-use-accessor-to-bring-in-foreign-columns) and [Accessing related models with django-tables2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461480/accessing-related-models-with-django-tables2)

Using: foreigncolumn = tables.Column(accessor='foreignmodel.foreigncolumnname'), I only see a '--'...

```
# The models:

class Organism(models.Model):
        species_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        strain_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        eukaryotic = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        lipids = models.ManyToManyField('Lipid',blank=True)

class Lipid(models.Model):
    lm_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

#The tables

class OrganismTable(tables.Table):
    name  = tables.LinkColumn('catalog:organism-detail', text=lambda record: record.species_name, args=[A('pk')])
    lp = tables.Column(accessor='Lipid.common_name')
    class Meta:
        model = Organism
        sequence = ['name','lp']
        exclude = ['id','species_name']
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, you would have to use `'lipids'` in the accessor string. Then, what do you want displayed there? The names of all the `Lipid` instances associated with the organism?

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl!  I already tried with lower-case lipids (also Lipids, Lipid, lipid) and it is not working either.... And yes, I would like to display all the lipid instances associated to the Organism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work so easily for `ManyToManyFields` because of the simple way `Accessor` works. You could display the `repr` of the related  `QuerySet` via `'lipids.all'` but that does not seem sufficient here. You can, however, add a property (or method) to your `Organism` model and use it in the accessor. This way, you can display any custom information related to the instance:

```
class Organism(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def lipid_names(self):
        return ', '.join(l.common_name for l in self.lipids.all())  # or similar

class OrganismTable(tables.Table):
    # ...
    lp = tables.Column(accessor='lipid_names')
```

I would recommend then to add a `prefetch_related('lipids')` to the `Organism` `QuerySet` that you pass to the table for better performance.

Comment: Yes! Great! It worked! Tanks mate! You saved my day! Night actually here in Australia! Really appreciated, now I can go to sleep!

Comment: One thing: you can only order the table by non-db-field-columns if your table data is not a queryset, but a python list, so might want to make the column `orderable=False` or turn the queryset into list ;)

Comment: This worked great~ I am wondering though, if i want to add a multi-field filter, what do you suggest? I changed my qs to a list since i need to filter, but then i cannot use django-filter as it seems to only accept a queryset (and it will also not let me filter on this property). Any ideas?